# MAX and AVG inside SELECT doesn't work

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

I have two query which work separate:

```
SELECT avg(priv_even_price) FROM private_event;
```

which outputs

```
"AVG(PRIV_EVEN_PRICE)"        
"387.833333333333333333333333333333333333"
```

and

```
SELECT max(priv_even_price) FROM private_event;
```

which outputs

```
"MAX(PRIV_EVEN_PRICE)"        
"950"
```

Why doesn't it work if i combine these two, I get an error in the following query:

```
SELECT max(priv_even_price) - (SELECT avg(priv_even_price) FROM private_event)
FROM private_event;

ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 39
```

Comment: Try SELECT max(priv_even_price) - avg(priv_even_price) FROM private_event;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't write `SELECT` each time, just call the function as part of the expression.

```
SELECT MAX(priv_even_price) - AVG(priv_even_price)
FROM private_event;
```

Comment: This works even better haha, stupid that I didn't think of trying this!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT
    (SELECT max(priv_even_price) FROM private_event)
  - (SELECT avg(priv_even_price) FROM private_event) AS Difference
```

Comment: Thanks this works I only added DISTINCT because I got multiple rows;)!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max(priv_even_price)-avg(priv_even_price) "Difference" FROM private_event
```